# Index based text clustering

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

Currently I am working on projet to cluster 2 millions of Text Memos. My objective is to create a standard for these Memos (Actually, when I say Memo, I mean text containing the description of something). To do so, I want first to cluster similar memos (gathering those which are probably having the same meaning) and then create a label for each cluster or group.

Since I am new to NLP, I want to know how to proceed to do so and what are some references / materials and similar projects that have been done before ?

I bet this a classic problem in NLP and many projects have been done about that subject.

I can work with R and Python

Answer (score 0):

Finding hidden topics in unstructured data like text, which accurately represent the document is called Topic Modelling.

[Gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/index.html) is a great library using which you can find Memos with similar topic. It has LSA and LDA algorithms implemented in python. The difference between LSA and LDA is in their implementation. LSA is a online learning algorithm, which means if the nature of data changes, it will reorient itself.

[topicmodels](https://cran.r-project.org/package=topicmodels) is the R package that implements LDA. Here is a quick tutorial on [LDA](https://www.tidytextmining.com/topicmodeling.html).

Comment: Yes ! is there any end to end guide for this ?